# Formula excel Promedio con condiciones

Tags: excel

tengo 4 celdas donde quiero sumar el valor de las 4 luego dividir entre 4 y condidicionar que: 
si el total da un valor de 4 o menos ponga un 1
si el total da 6 o menos pona un 2
si el total da un 8 o menos de un 3
si el total da un 9 exacto ponga un 4

Pero me marca error, soy nuevo en excel, si me puede instruir por favor
Esta es la formula que intente sin exito

```
=SI(SUMA(F15:I15)/4<=4,1),SI(SUMA(F15:I15)/4<=6,2),SI(SUMA(F15:I15)/4<=8,3),SI(SUMA(F15:I15)/4=9,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

La estructura que necesitas es la siguiente:

```
=SI(PRUEBA_LOGICA; VALOR SI VERDADERO; SI(PRUEBA_LOGICA, VALOR_SI_VERDADERO; SI(...))... ;VALOR SI FALSO)
```

Esto te permite anidar todos los si's que quieras, definiendo siempre el caso verdadero de cada prueba lógica, es decir, lo que devuelve la fórmula en caso que tu prueba lógica sea verdadera, y anidar en el si no, el resto de casos, siempre definiendo los valor si verdadero.

Al final, te queda un valor si falso por no continuar anidando si's: Esto es lo que devolverá la fórmula si no entra en ningún caso positivo, es decir, si no se cumplen ninguna de las pruebas lógicas que has definido.

Comment: Avisame si necesitas más ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

`=SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=4,1,SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=6,2,SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=8,3,SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)=9;4,"OTRO RESULTADO"))))`

No has especificado qué pasa si el resultado del promedio es mayor que 9, por eso he añadido lo de OTRO RESULTADO.

Si eso no puede suceder nunca, entonces usa:

`=SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=4,1,SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=6,2,SI(PROMEDIO(F15:I15)<=8,3,4,)))`